# Setting locale for globalize in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, globalize

I connected globalize to my project. The main aim was to translate some fields in my Book.rb Model via ActiveAdmin. I also added select input to Book page in Active Admin with set of locales (I18n). How can I pass locale when I submit form (updates Book), so that translation would be saved in that locale?

Globalize documentation doesn't have enough examples. They suggest we can use Book.attributes{title: "some title", locale: :en}. But I have no idea how to implement that for my case.

admin/Book.rb
...

```
permit_params :title, :pages

form do |f|
 inputs "Book info" do
  input :title
  input :pages
  input :set_locale as :select, collection => [:ru, :en]
 end
  actions
end
```

...